# Direct quotation vs indirect quotation

Tags: peer-review, quotation

I submitted a manuscript to IEEE Transactions on Intelligent Transportation Systems, which is a [journal for computer science applications and automotive/mechanical engineering](https://www.scimagojr.com/journalsearch.php?q=18378&tip=sid&clean=0). A reviewer of my manuscript made the following comment:

> "please rephrase direct quotations into indirect quotations as a better citation style"

Although this reviewer made excellent comments, I have my doubts about this comment. I prefer a direct quotation because of the following reasons:

- The previous authors (from which I am quoting) already chose their words wisely (I assume), so why trying to find another (possibly worse) way of phrasing?
- Using a direct quotation, it is clearer what my claim (that comes after the quotation) is based on. With an indirect quotation, one needs to read the reference to judge whether I interpreted the cited reference correctly.

I wonder:

- Are there good reasons to prefer indirect quotations (as suggested by the reviewer)?
- If direct quotations are preferred, what would be the polite way to convince the reviewer of this?

Comment: I think this depends really heavily on the field, so it would probably be good to specify your field in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the remark! Just added this information at the start of the post.

Comment: Terence Tao has given a fairly elaborate explanation on why you should avoid using direct quotation in [this blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/advice-on-writing-papers/write-in-your-own-voice/). You might want to check this out.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at the blog post!

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that "indirect quotation" is the same as "paraphrasing"?

Comment: That is indeed how I interpreted the reviewer's comment.

Answer (score 2):

The preference for direct vs indirect quotations varies strongly with the field. In mathematics and computer science, we just usually don't use direct quotations[1](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/advice-on-writing-papers/write-in-your-own-voice/), whereas they seem to be the standard in many humanities. Outside of rare occassions where an author you cite has used such a remarkable phrasing that you really, really, really need to use a direct quotation, the case for going against the prevailing customs of your field just doesn't seem to be there.

While I personally view this mostly as a matter of convention, Ken Hung has pointed out in the comments that Terrence Tao argues against using direct quotations on [his blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/advice-on-writing-papers/write-in-your-own-voice/).

[1](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/advice-on-writing-papers/write-in-your-own-voice/) Something to mention here is that definition and theorem statements are a special case for referencing in mathematics. We don't paraphrase them (much), but also don't use the usual formatting of direct quotations.